# jquery $().load not working

Tags: jquery, timer

Okay, so I've been looking for an answer for hours and I can't figure out why this isn't working:

```
function updateClock(){
setInterval(function() {
        $(".time").load("/real/js/time.php", function(data){
            $(".time").empty().append(data);
        });
}, 1000);
```

}

The console sees that it is trying to load, but the content of the page isn't actually changing. It's a PHP clock I have, it has to be in PHP I can't use a JS clock.

Comment: are you sure that your link is correct? php file in js folder!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`load()` inserts the content automagically, so when you do the same in the callback, you're overwriting the content :

```
function updateClock(){
    setInterval(function() {
        $(".time").empty().load("/real/js/time.php");
    }, 1000);
}
```

EDIT: sounds like you have a caching problem, try:

```
function updateClock(){
    setInterval(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type : 'GET',
            url  : '/real/js/time.php',
            cache: false
        }).done(function( data ) {
            $(".time").html(data);
        });
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: That isn't changing the content, it still comes up as the same thing as it was before. The content of time.php is constantly changing.

Comment: @lDucks - that sounds like a caching problem, or a problem with your PHP script, either way, load() does'nt return the data in the callback, it inserts it directly, so what you're doing won't work.

Comment: Thank you so much, it was a caching problem. I thought it might be but I couldn't figure out how to fix it.